# Is possible to uninstall docker desktop on MacOSX and keep docker docker-engine and VMs working?

Tags: macos, docker

I'm using docker for a while and when I installed it I didn't note if the command line and the GUI Docker desktop were installed as two separate things. So I want to uninstall only the docker desktop but keep the command line working on MACOSX 11.

Is that possible? How can I do that?

Comment: docker desktop might the engine wihout which docker command line may not work. Double check on their website.

Comment: If the issue is due to docker desktop being paid now there's this option: https://arnon.me/2021/09/replace-docker-with-minikube/